# In Jira Wiki format only part of word

Tags: formatting, jira, wiki, cpu-word

When i write in Jira wiki page:

```
player*Id*
```

I want only part of word to be formatted (bold): "Id". But jira writes it literaly:

```
player*Id*
```

I want it to write:

player**Id**

If i make whole playerId bold, it works though. How to make only part of word bold in jira wiki?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's not possible, as parser requires spaces next to asterisks to display it correctly.
What you can do is to use color instead:

```
Player{color:red}Id{color}
```

Which would be displayed like this:

[image]